# Problem reading three simultaneous key press input using pynput library python

Tags: python, pynput

I'm trying to read three key press together using the pynput python library to simulate a game-like robot drive in ROS. It's working quite all right but the problem is that when ever I press the **left arrow key** with any other key, the last (third) key is not being read. I've tried the code on another PC and it had the same problem.
I believe the best way to understand what I'm trying to say is to just play with the code which I'll paste below (you can change the key.left to any other key e.g key.page_up):

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, KeyCode, Listener

## ###     read combination of more than one key i.e three keys      #####
## ###     one can also apply it to two keys by making the key_buffer array to take two elements      #####

key_buffer = [None, None, None]

def press(key):
    global key_buffer
    if key == Key.up:
        if key not in key_buffer:
            if None in key_buffer:
                key_buffer[key_buffer.index(None)] = key
                print(key_buffer)
    elif key == Key.down:
        if key not in key_buffer:
            if None in key_buffer:
                key_buffer[key_buffer.index(None)] = key
                print(key_buffer)
    elif key == Key.left:
        if key not in key_buffer:
            if None in key_buffer:
                key_buffer[key_buffer.index(None)] = key
                print(key_buffer)
    elif key == Key.right:
        if key not in key_buffer:
            if None in key_buffer:
                key_buffer[key_buffer.index(None)] = key
                print(key_buffer)
    elif key == Key.alt:
        if key not in key_buffer:
            if None in key_buffer:
                key_buffer[key_buffer.index(None)] = key
                print(key_buffer)
    elif key == Key.space:
        if key not in key_buffer:
            if None in key_buffer:
                key_buffer[key_buffer.index(None)] = key
                print(key_buffer)
    
def release(key):
    global key_buffer
    if key == Key.up:
        if key in key_buffer:
            key_buffer[key_buffer.index(key)] = None
            print(key_buffer)
    elif key == Key.down:
        if key in key_buffer:
            key_buffer[key_buffer.index(key)] = None
            print(key_buffer)
    elif key == Key.left:
        if key in key_buffer:
            key_buffer[key_buffer.index(key)] = None
            print(key_buffer)
    elif key == Key.right:
        if key in key_buffer:
            key_buffer[key_buffer.index(key)] = None
            print(key_buffer)
    elif key == Key.alt:
        if key in key_buffer:
            key_buffer[key_buffer.index(key)] = None
            print(key_buffer)
    elif key == Key.space:
        if key in key_buffer:
            key_buffer[key_buffer.index(key)] = None
            print(key_buffer)
    
def main():
    listener = Listener(on_press=press, on_release=release)
    listener.start()
    listener.join()


if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

do remember to install to pynput library before you try the code above

```
pip3 install pynput
```

I just want to know what is causing the problem and possible solution to it.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have posted works on the machine I am running (M1 MacBook Pro). However, I will propose an alternative way to capture three simultaneous key presses:

```py
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

allowedKeys = [
    Key.up,
    Key.down,
    Key.left,
    Key.right,
    Key.alt,
    Key.space
]

key_buffer = []

def press(key):
    global key_buffer
    if key in allowedKeys and key not in key_buffer and len(key_buffer) < 3:
        key_buffer.append(key)
        print(key_buffer)

def realease(key):
    global key_buffer
    
    if(key in key_buffer):
        key_buffer.pop( key_buffer.index(key) )
        print(key_buffer)

def main():
    listener = Listener(on_press=press, on_release=realease)
    listener.start()
    listener.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The above code adds the currently pressed key to `key_buffer`, as long as the length of `key_buffer` is less than three, the key is an allowed key, and the length of `key_buffer` is less than 3.

To remove the key, we just check if it the `key_buffer` contains the currently released key, and if it does pop it from the list